# POST Call to an API with an XML in PHP

Tags: php, api, rest

I'm trying to make a call to an API supposed to return me a XML to create a Label for an order.

I've got this documentation :

```
Type of request:
GET

URL PROD:
https://api.bpost.be/services/shm/{accountID}/orders/{OrderReference}/labels/{size}

Headers for PDF labels:
Authorization: Basic AccountID:pass-phrase (base64)
Content-Type: application/vnd.bpost.shm-labelRequest-v3+XML
Accept: application/vnd.bpost.shm-label-pdf-v3+XML
```

It's working fine when I'm trying the parameters in Rest Console, but I'm fairly new with PHP so I have trouble implementing it.

My code so far :

```
    <?php 
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.bpost.shm-labelRequest-v3+XML');
header('Accept: application/vnd.bpost.shm-label-pdf-v3+XML');
header('Authorization: Basic MTE4MDI1OjEyMzQ=');

function createLabel(){
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.bpost.be/services/shm/ID/orders/1634/labels/A6');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

return $resp;
}

createLabel();

?>
```

Anybody got an idea about this ?

EDIT : 
I've been going with file_get_contents again :

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  =>    ["Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password"),
                        "Accept: application/vnd.bpost.shm-label-pdf-v3+XML",
                        "Content-Type: application/vnd.bpost.shm-labelRequest-v3+XML"]
        )
    ));

    $res = file_get_contents('https://api.bpost.be/services/shm/118025/orders/1638/labels/A6', false, $context);

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($res);

    var_dump($res);
    var_dump($xml);
```

Result of the 2 var_dump :

```
string(319) "" object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (0) { }
```

So i guess I retrieve some informations, but how can I extract it ?
This API call is supposed to give me a PDF ..

Comment: What is the response status?

Comment: You'd actually be better off using `file_get_contents(...)` rather than a CURL request

Comment: I tried with file_get_content too, but i've got the same result, it's only downloading me an empty .php file

Comment: If the API is supposed to give you a PDF, don't parse it as if it's xml.

Comment: Without parsing it, all it gives to me is **string(319) ""**, and I don't really know what to do with it

Answer (score 1):

You are not printing anything so maybe it returns xml and you just cannot see the result .. Try var_dump( createLabel());

Answer (score 0):

The line with headers are the RESPONSE headers to your own request:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.bpost.shm-labelRequest-v3+XML');
header('Accept: application/vnd.bpost.shm-label-pdf-v3+XML');
header('Authorization: Basic MTE4MDI1OjEyMzQ=');
```

So those headers are coming back with your request; you need to add them to the curl request:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('HeaderName: HeaderValue','HeaderName2: HeaderValue2'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem, maybe it's no longer relevant to you but I solved it with the following code.

```
$username = 'accountid';
$password = 'passphrase';

$context = stream_context_create(array(
            'http' => array(
                'header'  =>    ["Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password"),
                                "Content-Type: application/vnd.bpost.shm-labelRequest-v3+XML",
                                "Accept: application/vnd.bpost.shm-label-pdf-v3+XML"]
            )
        ));

$res = file_get_contents('https://api.bpost.be/services/shm/'.$username.'/orders/'.$order.'/labels/A6', false, $context);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($res);

foreach($xml->label as $item) {
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="bpost_'.$order.'.pdf"');
    echo base64_decode((string)$item->bytes);
}
```

It's important to know that each label only can be printed once by this call. So the second time the results will be empty. I suggest storing the results the first time.